# python pandas one- hot encoding in several columns for the same question

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have to perform one-hot encoding on the data frames that contain the survey results.

In this data frames, they represented 'multiple response' in multiple columns. for example, if someone choose '1' and '3', it is represented by '1'in first columns and '3' in second columns.

I need to organize the data like this way

| Quesion1 | Quesion1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |

-->

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I tried to use 'get_dummies' to do one-hot encoding. but two columns are treated  as different question.
('2' in first question and '2' in second question are treated like different values)

Is there any good solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).groupby(level=0).sum().clip(upper=1)

   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0  0  1
```

- flatten the frame with `stack`
- get the dummies
- groupby each row (now at level=0)
- sum the 1s but max-clip at 1 for possible multiple occurences (i.e., same answers for questions)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.get_dummies()` to converto to one-hot for each column and then join them using `pd.concat()`:

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df.loc[:, column]) for column in df.columns], axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: not the desired output actually

Comment: @Mustafa Aydın It is now the desired outcome using a simpler approach.

Comment: maybe you can make a list comprehension or something to generalize this to any number of columns

Answer (score 0):

Using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = df.stack().droplevel(1)

out = pd.crosstab(s.index, s).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0  0  1
```